# Null Set Symbol

Tags: notation

My professor pitched me a problem like so, 2∅(25) mod 25 ≡ ?

The answer is 1. However, after much browsing of the internet, I couldn't find anything to justify this answer. I was wondering exactly how she came to this conclusion.

Comment: Professors have terrible handwriting.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what the symbol ∅ means in this context.  Is it some sort of binary arithmetic operation?

Comment: That is not the empty set.  It's Euler's totient function.

Comment: @Batominovski please post as answer.

Comment: Even if @Batominovski is right, it might still be either $2\phi(25)$ or $2^{\phi(25)}$ ...

Comment: @djechlin:  While the suggestion of Euler's totient function is a good one, it will not get us to "the answer is 1" by itself.  Possibly the subexpression is meant to be an exponent on base $2$.

Comment: @hardmath well, firstly $2\cdot 20 \not\cong 1 \mod 25$ so that clears that up. I'll post it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi$, defined as $\phi(n) = |\{a < n : a, n \text{ are relatively prime}\}|$.

$\phi(25) = 20$ and we have $2^{20} \cong 1 \mod 25$.

This holds in general. If $a$ and $n$ are coprime then we have $a^{\phi(n)} \cong 1 \mod n$. This is called Euler's theorem. Taking $p = 1$ so $\phi(p) = p-1$, we have Fermat's Little Theorem as a special case: $a^{p-1} \cong 1 \mod p$, or $a^p \cong a \mod p$.